# How to set Facebook login permissions when using a custom login button in Android

Tags: android, facebook, social-authentication

I am following this guide to set up social login via Facebook in my Android app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions

With Facebook's `LoginButton` setting the callback to handle user authentication result is easy:

```
facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
final LoginButton facebookLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.facebook);
facebookLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Collections.singletonList(EMAIL));
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                final String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });
```

But when I swap `LoginButton` with other Android button, I can no longer user the `setReadPermissions` function.

My question is: How do I request user's email permission from Facebook when using a custom login button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onClickListener` on your custom button and call `logInWithReadPermissions` method on `LoginManager` inside `onClick`. This method accepts a list of permissions to request from the user.

Complete example:

```
facebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
final MyFacebookButton facebookLoginButton = findViewById(R.id.facebook);
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(facebookCallbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });
facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LoginManager
                .getInstance()
                .logInWithReadPermissions(
                        LoginActivity.this,
                        Collections.singletonList(EMAIL)
                );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());

mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("Success", "Login");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button btn_fb_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_login);

btn_fb_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    }
});

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    return;
}
}
```